# Android RelativeLayout placing objects in corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place 4 objects in the four corners of a list view item. I am using Relative Layout. For some reason the objects are aligning to the left side only. 2 objects should be on the right. I am also using layout_gravity, but no use. They all align to the left.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fromDistanceWindowLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        layout="@layout/include_distance_window" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toDistanceWindowLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        layout="@layout/include_distance_window" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fromTimeWindowLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        layout="@layout/include_time_window" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toTimeWindowLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        layout="@layout/include_time_window" />
```

Include include_distance_window.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/distancebackground"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distanceWindow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Include include_time_window

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/distancebackground" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeWindow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:text="123"/>
```

Edit : 
If I replace the 2nd include with the contents of the include xml it all works fine

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/distancebackground"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceWindow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wonder why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I want to Point out. Layout gravity has no effect in Relative Layout. It is a parameter of Linear Layout. 2nd, if you are using eclipse IDE, please check the graphic layout. I want to know if you are able to see all the relative Layouts? I guess Instead of giving wrap content for the Relative Layouts, you can try giving some definite values, say 70dp. Please try these, tinker and let me know the changes.

Comment: Smart changes. Yes, that made a difference, the children did start to do in corner's. And yes, gravity made no difference.

Comment: I just now finished something similar. Glad to help :D. Timing and situation.